# Problem chrome content security policy react extension manifest

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I created a very simple extension chrome but I have a problem I can not fix it, the problem is of Content Security Policy of google chrome please I need help for fix it 
and this is the error :

Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' blob: filesystem: chrome-extension-resource:". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-wkEhk1Pm58HZQSzT/oPAcIeUYSsJpEEGo2v2M1aGgTs='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5nI9.png)

Comment: Use a separate js file, [more info](/a/25721457).

Answer (score 4):

React by default uses inline scripts which your browser will reject in an extension. Create a .env.production file in your react app and specify `INLINE_RUNTIME_CHUNK=false` inside of it.

Source: https://gist.github.com/amad-person/f0ef85a2123a2e1fcf8052dcf09eef90

You can also do this by updating the build script in package.json file

```
"build": "INLINE_RUNTIME_CHUNK=false react-scripts build"
```